# Unable to use $facts as a hash in the puppet manifest

Tags: puppet, facter

Here is the manifest code which is failing:

```
each( $facts['partitions'] ) |$name, $device| {
  notice( "${facts['hostname']} has device ${name} with size ${device['size']}" )
}
```

The error:

```
[manifests]$puppet apply /vagrant/manifests/mountpoints.pp
Error: Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value. at /vagrant/manifests/mountpoints.pp:1:7 on node siy
Error: Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value. at /vagrant/manifests/mountpoints.pp:1:7 on node siy
```

The facter command works fine:

```
[manifests]$facter partitions
{"vda1"=>{"uuid"=>"050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a", "size"=>"41943040", "mount"=>"/", "label"=>"DOROOT", "filesystem"=>"ext4"}}
```

Puppet version is 3.8.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Your code is fine and works for me with Facter 2.4.6 and Puppet 4.7.0. For some reason it is not resolving `$facts['fact_key']` as a fact hash and instead seems to be treating it like something else. Are you having future parser issues again?

Comment: @Matt Schuchard, it looks like $partitions work fine, but not $facts['partitions']. As you said some issue with array usage. I do have parser equal to future in the puppet.conf. I will see if I can upgrade to puppet 4 and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: `$::partitions` is the old syntax for facts inside of Puppet. I would definitely recommend switching to Puppet 4.5.3 or 4.6.2 for a modern stable version, especially since 3.8 is EOL by the end of the year. Also, that is a hash and not an array. Is your book explaining what that code is doing or just showing examples and expecting you to guess?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually found that puppet 3.x defaults the setting stringify_facts to true, which was causing the problem when the code tried to access $facts as an array.

From the pupppet documentation at 
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/deprecated_settings.html#stringifyfacts--true

> This setting defaults to true, which disables structured facts and coerces all fact values to strings. You can enable structured facts by setting stringify_facts = false in puppet.conf on every agent node and Puppet master..

If you want to use $facts as an hash/structure, then the configuration options stringify_facts shall be set to false and trusted_node_data set to true. The behaviors represented by these configuration settings are the defaults in the puppet 4, and are necessary for a successful migration.

Comment: I had to set trusted_node_data = true in puppet 3.8

Comment: One more issue!  I set trusted_node_data = true and stringify_facts = false and the problem was Still not fixed for me.  My solution was installing puppetlabs-stdlib .  Without stdlib puppet can't do many things documentation claims it can do.

Comment: @johndavid Correct. Unless you're writing your own modules entirely though, any Supported module is going to have stdlib as a dependency.