# Access Facter hash key in Puppet

Tags: puppet, facter

I am creating a manifest to get an Agent's partition name.

The fact `$partitions` shows the detail of the partition info.

```
{"xvda1"=>{"uuid"=>"d1697425-49d0-4c9f-9901-5f9260be8196", "size"=>"83859300", "mount"=>"/", "label"=>"cloudimg-rootfs", "filesystem"=>"ext4"}}
```

But, I just want to get the name part (`xvda1`) and use it as a variable for a configuration file.

Is there any way to filter the output in Puppet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way to solve this would be to use the `keys` function from `puppetlabs/stdlib`: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/readme.

> keys()
>   Returns the keys of a hash as an array. Type: rvalue.

With that function, we can transform the output hash from Facter into an array of the keys and access its elements normally. Assuming that `xvda1` is the `0th` element,

Facter 2:

$variable = keys($::partitions)[0]

Facter 3:

$variable = keys($facts['partitions'])[0]

Comment: I tried it but got an error Facter 2 : "Error while evaluating a Function Call, keys(): Requires hash to work with at" Facter 3 : "Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value"

Comment: @Mike Those imply the fact was not looked up correctly. Is `$partitions` the name of the fact you wanted? Did you make a typo on the fact name?

Comment: Yes the $partitions is the fact I want     $hddname = keys($::partitions)[0]
file {'puppet_facts_example':
  path    => '/tmp/test.txt',
  content => " HDDname is $hddname",} I got a hash error.

Comment: I found the solution for hash issue from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330166/unable-to-use-facts-as-a-hash-in-the-puppet-manifest?rq=1  Thanks Matt

Comment: @Mike Your problem was you were using a too-old version of Puppet? That was how I solved the problem in that question.

Comment: So, @Mike, the problem was with `stringify_facts`?  In that event, your question is misleading: if `stringify_facts` is enabled then the fact value was not what you presented in the first place.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I used version 3.8.1 and the default stringify_facts was true. After I changed it to false, everything was ok. Finally I upgraded the master to 4.8.1 and stringify_facts is false by default in 4.8.1

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes I used version 3.8.1 and I had to change the stringify_facts to false to make your suggestion ( $variable = keys($::partitions)[0]) work. Finally I upgrade the master to 4.8.1.